# How to manage multiple sheets within a NavigationStack in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am working with sheets in SwiftUI and recently found a problem with navigation while a sheet is already open.
In the code below i have a navigation stack that navigates to two different detail view:

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var navigationPath = NavigationPath()

var body: some View {
    NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
        VStack {
            Text("Go to first detail")
            Button("Submit") {
                navigationPath.append("FirstDetail")
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { value in
            if value == "FirstDetail" {
                FirstDetailView(path: $navigationPath)
            }
            
            if value == "SecondDetail" {
                SecondDetailView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the code below is my first detail view that already present sheet and also has button to navigate to second detail view:

```
struct FirstDetailView: View {
@Binding var path: NavigationPath
@State var isPresented = true

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello First!")
        Button("GoToSecond", action: {
            path.append("SecondDetail")
        })
        Spacer()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.yellow)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
        SheetDetailView(title: "First")
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
    })
}
```

also in my second detail view, i have another sheet:

```
struct SecondDetailView: View {

@State var isPresented = true

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text("Hello Second")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .background(.green)
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
        SheetDetailView(title: "Second")
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
            .interactiveDismissDisabled()
            .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
    })
}
}
// HERE IS MY SHEET DETAIL VIEW
struct SheetDetailView: View {
var title: String

var body: some View {
    Text("Hello \(title)")
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(.red)
}
}
```

the result will be like this:

[image]

So my issue is that navigation to another view while the first sheet is open causes this sheet to appear in the second detail view so each of detailview first and second has its own sheet, and also I want to know what is the best approach for this issue.

Comment: So you want the first sheet to be dismissed when you navigate to `SecondDetailView`?

Comment: You probably need to create your own SwiftUI sheet view modifier so it attaches to the parent vs the root.

Comment: @Sweeper i don't want to first sheet dismissed I want to navigate to SecondDetailView with the SecondDetailView sheet also when I tap back on navigation go to FirstDetailView with its sheet presented

Comment: @loremipsum could you explain a little more

Comment: So you mean the second sheet will be presented on top of the first sheet, and dismissing the second sheet will cause the first sheet to be visible?

Comment: @Sweeper yes exactly

Comment: @Sweeper of course when the back button is taped on the navigation show the first sheet not dismissing the second sheet.
so each of detailview first and second has their own sheet

Comment: .sheet more often than not uses rootViewController.present() what might work is something like parent.present(). You can only achieve that with your own version of a UIKit modal presentation. Because sheet uses the root it doesn’t matter where you present the sheet from it will always show at the root.

Comment: @loremipsum so I think I should use a custom view instead of presentDetent to approach my solution or using UIKit

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found to make the current sheet close and the next one open is by doing some trickery with DispatchQueses:

```
struct FirstDetailView: View {
    @Binding var path: NavigationPath
    @State var isPresented = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello First!")
            Button("GoToSecond", action: {
                isPresented = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
                    path.append("SecondDetail")
                }
            })
            Spacer()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.yellow)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            SheetDetailView(title: "First")
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
        })
    }
}

struct SecondDetailView: View {
    
    @State var isPresented = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello Second")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                .background(.green)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPresented, content: {
            SheetDetailView(title: "Second")
                .presentationDetents([.medium, .large])
                .interactiveDismissDisabled()
                .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled)
        })
        .onAppear {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
                isPresented = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been seeing weird glitchy stuff recently on SwiftUI behalf.
Let me know if this solution is good enough for you!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm wondering if there might be a simpler way to handle this without employing concurrency. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I can try playing around a bit more with it tomorrow.

Comment: @RezaKhonsari another way I can think of is designing your own custom sheet and displaying it using the overlay modifier.

Comment: Yes Mat I think a custom sheet is a way I should go.

Comment: Tell me if you need help.